# regexreplace and regexextract with japanese characters

Tags: regex, google-sheets

These functions not work with Japanese characters within parenthesis, and it does not work with Japanese parenthesis on either side of text.  Both are issues that stop me from doing what I want.

Two formats I've tried:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(C3, "\(([A-Za-z]+)\)")
=REGEXEXTRACT (C3,"~（ (.*) ~）")
```

The Errors:

`Error
Function REGEXEXTRACT
parameter 2 value "\(([A-Za-z]+)\)"
does not match text of Function
REGEXEXTRACT parameter 1
value "(これ)をください。".`

`Error
Function REGEXEXTRACT parameter 2 value "~（ (.*) ~）" does not match text of Function REGEXEXTRACT parameter 1 value "それを（一[ひと]つ）ください。".`

For regexreplace it will just copy a cell without replacing anything.

I've run out of ideas of what to do to fix this.

Edit: To clarify, I'm trying to move a Japanese string from within Japanese parenthesis to a new cell.  Then I will replace the Japanese string within the parenthesis with another string.

Answer (score 1):

Finally got it to work.

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A3,"（(.+)）")
=REGEXEXTRACT(A3,CHAR(65288)&"(.+)"&CHAR(65289))
=REGEXREPLACE(A3,CHAR(65288)&"(.+)"&CHAR(65289),"string replace")
```